# SMART - Seek Error Rate

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have read that seek errors is an incremented count of track seeks and that the count resets to zero after a fixed number of thousands of seek commands. This is evident in some of the BackBlaze hard drives (see Figure 1 below).

[image: Figure 1]

In Figure 1 the seek rate for the hard drive increases up to and including day 234. The count is then reset on day 235.

Is this incremental count just the total time that the drive has taken to locate a specific piece of stored data?

Does anyone know why this count is reset and if it means anything? I.e. does resetting just reset the count or does it perhaps mean that the disks seek rate is restored to as good as new at day 235?

[image: Figure2]

I am wondering if I can visualise the seek error rate as in Figure 2. Figure 2 (if my understanding is correct) is the total time that the drive has taken to locate a specific piece of stored data without the count rest at day 235. If the count reset does not improve the health of the disk, or if it does not affect the seek rate after the count is reset, then I guess this is fine.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` so I can see if there's a reason for the seek errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot show this as I am not showing data from my own hard drive. This is the seek error rate for a particular hard drive from the Backblaze dataset which is available online.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Backblaze, so I guess that I can't help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counters are reset like an odometer rolling over after running out of integers. Many device controllers will have different thresholds, but a 0 count does not mean that the drive is without errors, just as a vehicle with 1,000,010km on the odometer is not "fresh off the assembly line".

If you would like to build a graph as seen in Figure 2, you could write a little data collection utility that reads the SMART information off your storage device and records it in a database (or anywhere you see fit, really). The [smartmontools](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/smartctl.8.html) package is the one I usually reach for to display storage device info.

You can install it like this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Install the `smartmontools` package:

   ```
   sudo apt install smartmontools
   ```
2. Query a storage medium, for example, an NVMe device:

   ```
   sudo smartctl --all /dev/nvme0n1
   ```

   This will give you *a lot* of information:

   ```
   smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-17-generic] (local build)
   Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

   === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
   Model Number:                       SAMSUNG MZVLW512HMJP-000L7
   Serial Number:                      S359NX0K103156
   Firmware Version:                   7L7QCXY7
   PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
   IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
   Total NVM Capacity:                 512,110,190,592 [512 GB]
   Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
   Controller ID:                      2
   NVMe Version:                       1.2
   Number of Namespaces:               1
   Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          512,110,190,592 [512 GB]
   Namespace 1 Utilization:            81,254,830,080 [81.2 GB]
   Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
   Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 b181b5c4a3
   Local Time is:                      Thu May 27 21:57:29 2021 JST
   Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
   Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
   Optional NVM Commands (0x001f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
   Log Page Attributes (0x03):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg
   Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     69 Celsius
   Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     72 Celsius

   Supported Power States
   St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
    0 +     7.60W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
    1 +     6.00W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
    2 +     5.10W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
    3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1500
    4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2200    6000

   Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
   Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
    0 +     512       0         0

   === START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
   SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

   SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
   Critical Warning:                   0x00
   Temperature:                        33 Celsius
   Available Spare:                    100%
   Available Spare Threshold:          10%
   Percentage Used:                    1%
   Data Units Read:                    20,937,566 [10.7 TB]
   Data Units Written:                 26,780,407 [13.7 TB]
   Host Read Commands:                 359,002,242
   Host Write Commands:                683,010,154
   Controller Busy Time:               5,130
   Power Cycles:                       1,027
   Power On Hours:                     3,812
   Unsafe Shutdowns:                   85
   Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
   Error Information Log Entries:      719
   Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
   Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
   Temperature Sensor 1:               33 Celsius
   Temperature Sensor 2:               39 Celsius

   Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
   Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
     0        719     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
     1        718     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
     2        717     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
     3        716     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
     4        715     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
     5        714     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
     6        713     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
     7        712     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
     8        711     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
     9        710     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
    10        709     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
    11        708     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
    12        707     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
    13        706     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
    14        705     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
    15        704     0  0x0008  0x4004      -            0     0     -
   ... (48 entries not read)
   ```

   This is probably a bit too much information, so you can get *just* the error counts like this:

   ```
   sudo smartctl -l error /dev/nvme0n1
   ```

   The above command returns the same output as seen in the "Error Information" section from the previous command. Note that NVMe devices will return at most 16 entries by default. If you are querying an NVMe device that has more, you can specify the number of entries to return like this:

   ```
   sudo smartctl -l error,64 /dev/nvme0n1
   ```

   For my device, there are 64 flash storage chips in total, so I would add `,64` to the command above. You can show information for up to 256 entries.

Hope this gives you a wealth of information to play with and track.

Comment: Very interesting. Just to clarify, the seek error rate only resets for ease of storing smaller numbers? If the seek counts were on a much smaller scale then the count would not need to be reset.